# Неправильно определяется максимальный элемент в классе очередь

Tags: c++, классы

```
class myQueue
{
  private:
    int size,
        *head,
        *tail,
        *data;

  public:
    myQueue(int size) // конструктор
           : size(size)
    {
        data = new int[size];
        head = data;
        tail = data + size - 1;
    }

    ~myQueue() // деструктор
    {
        delete[]data;
    }

    void input(int el, int& i)
    {
        data[i] = el;
    }


    void maxEl()
    {
        int max = *data;

        while (head != tail)
        {
            head++;

            if (*head > max)
            {
                max = *head;
            }
        }

        cout << max;
    }
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    myQueue q(5);
    int n = 0, el;

    while (n < 5)
    {
        cin >> el;
        q.input(el, n);
        n++;
    }

    q.maxEl();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Есть класс очередь, в которой нужно найти максимальный элемент. Но максимальным элементом всегда показывает первый элемент. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то ваш код выводит верно максимальное значение...
Но сам код вызывает массу вопросов.

Например, в конструкторе у вас получается массив с *мусором*. Вы не инициализируете массив...

Во-вторых, зачем в `input` индекс передается по ссылке? И вообще, какая же это **очередь**, если вы вставляете в нее элементы в произвольное место? Очередь должна иметь две функции - вставки элемента в конец, и снятия элемента из начала. А у вас?

В `maxEl` вы *изменяете*  значение `head`, так что после этого все ваши функции для работы с очередью работать более не могут...

И еще - функция не должна делать разнородные вещи - например, искать максимальный элемент и выводить его. Думаю, что ваша функция должна *возвращать* максимальный элемент, а *выводит* его пусть уж `main`, например.

Answer (score 1):

1. Во-первых, это не *очередь* - потому как *очередь* должна поддерживать операции извлечения/вставки элементов, а я тут этого не увидел.
2. Во-вторых, Ваша очередь становится одноразовой, после того как будет вызван метод `maxEl` - Вы меняете значение `head` - при повторном вызове обход начнется с последнего элемента. Если быть точнее, он вообще не начнется.